# Split cells with carriage returns where result starts in different row (same column) and don't remove existing formula

Tags: excel, vba, list, carriage-return

The code below splits then transposes the data, but the destination cell is also the cell that was being evaluated. As a result, it is overwriting the formula in the cell.
I need to keep the formula in the cell(s)and have the result start in a different cell (same column, different row). (See screenshot.)

Detail:
I have a report from a system that includes countless carriage returns within individual cells. (Some cells have over 2000 carriage returns.)
I need to split the cell contents into a vertical list for analysis, but I need the list to start in a cell lower down in the column.

The range of cells that have carriage return contents that need to be split: "h2:aa2".
Destination cells to start the list creation: "H8:aa8"

The code overwrites the formula that was in the cell.

1. How can I add the destination cell language into the code?
2. How can I remove blank rows in the destination cells?
   i.e. there is an extra carriage return between results. See screenshot.
   I can do this later using the Unique formula, but would love to not have to do that.

CODE:

```vb
Sub Splitcelldatawithcarriagereturnformultiplecolumns()
'VBA code to split out cell that has countless data with carriage returns
'Separates on carriage return, then transposes data. Result = vertical list"
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Range("h2:aw2")
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    lLFs = VBA.Len(Rng) - VBA.Len(VBA.Replace(Rng, vbLf, ""))
    If lLFs > 0 Then
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lLFs).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        Rng.Resize(lLFs + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VBA.Split(Rng, vbLf))
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Where I failed:
The section `For Each Rng In WorkRng` has `Rng` identified in countless locations as it splits then transposes the data. I tried replacing `Rng` with "H8:AA8" but that didn't work.

I believe I need to define the destination area, then assign it. (I also have found many different ways to remove the carriage return, but they seemed more cumbersome. (I am not sure if it is the most efficient code, but it works.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the lines in the adjacent cell related by position (City 1 <> A, City 2<>B, etc)?  E.g. here's no "D" in Col I but what if there was no "B"? - should there be a space left for that ?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the quick response. The short answer is no. Column H is not related to Col. "I" in the context of this request.  With that said, The longer answer and background is that City 1,2,3,..n that are all in the same cell (H2) all have identical characteristics which are presented in the next column "I2". View it as a grouping. The next row down H3 (not described in my request), has another group of cities with a different list of characteristics in "I3".   I will test and reach back out. Thanks so much!!

Comment: OK in that case the code I posted should do what you want.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I will re-evaluate in the morning to make sure I understand it all and Like the answer. Thank you so much Tim!!

Comment: Hi Tim, I found an issue, and have an additional request.  Issue: if data was input into  a cell from a previous run of the macro, (ie as part of the output range) when the macro runs again, it does not overwrite the existing contents.  How would you recommend adding a "wipe all cell contents in the output range". Start the code with that, or within the current code?

Comment: Additional Request:  I now have been requested to perform this macro on multiple tabs within a workbook. But,...it is not all tabs.  I originally thought I could just add a line of code to list out the individual worksheets names, but the code will break if anyone changes a tab name by accident...What would the code look like if it did a search for "Exceptions" within each tab name, then proceeded with the code, then loop to the next. Thoughts?

Comment: See edits below

Comment: I do have a follow-up question to split the data a little differently so it is completely flattened for analysis across tabs  Adding a screenshot below.  Please advise if I should create another ticket. Including here, as this is a progression now that I have been able to start analyzing the data. . I believe the screenshot is the best way to have a more "export" look that can easily be used for extensive analysis. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Probably best to start a new post for this.

Comment: Thank you Tim for all your help. Fantastic!  Hopefully you can help with the add on request. I wasn't sure how to link them. The name of the new Question is:             
Flatten data in table where cells contain carriage returns, then assign attributes with 1 to many conditions. Then, repeat across tabs and consolidate

Comment: Hmmm your new question had a super-long description but no code, so it looks like it got hammered and closed.  If you post a new question, try to make it look more like this one: include any code you already tried (describing what specific problem(s) you had with it), and avoid the "wall of text" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** added worksheet loop and tabname check, and clears previous output

You could do it like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitCells()

    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, v, arr, arr2, i As Long, x As Long, el
    Dim cOut As Range, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets                       '##loop all worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) Like "*exceptions*" Then     '##tabname contains "exceptions" ?
            For Each c In ws.Range("h2:aw2").Cells     'loop over range in row2
                
                Set cOut = c.EntireColumn.Cells(8)     'output starts here
                cOut.Resize(1000).ClearContents        '##clear any previous data
                
                v = Trim(c.Value)                      'remove any spaces
                If Len(v) > 0 Then                     'any content?
                    arr = Split(v, vbLf)                       'split on vbLf
                    ReDim arr2(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))     'for consolidated array
                    x = LBound(arr2)
                    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                        el = Trim(arr(i))
                        If Len(el) > 0 Then  'non-blank?
                            arr2(x) = el     'add to consolidated array
                            x = x + 1        'next position
                        End If
                    Next i
                    'drop the array onto the sheet below the cell being processed
                    If x > LBound(arr) Then 'EDIT: added this check
                        cOut.Resize(x).Value = Application.Transpose(arr2)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        End If      'tab name contains "exceptions"
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Your second scenario:

```vb
Sub SplitCells()

    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, rwData As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSumm As Worksheet, cOut As Range
    Dim arrJur, arrG1, arrG2, fileName, el
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook                'or ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSumm = wb.Worksheets("Summary")  'summary sheet
    Set cOut = wsSumm.Range("A2")          'output starts here
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets                       '##loop all worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) Like "*exceptions*" Then     '##tabname contains "exceptions" ?
            fileName = ws.Range("A1").Value
            Set rwData = ws.Range("A9:C9")
            Do While Application.CountA(rwData) > 0    'while have any data
                arrJur = CellValues(rwData.Cells(1))
                If Not IsEmpty(arrJur) Then            'any Jurisdictions?
                    arrG1 = CellValues(rwData.Cells(2))
                    arrG2 = CellValues(rwData.Cells(3))
                    For Each el In arrJur
                        cOut.Value = fileName               'file name
                        cOut.Offset(0, 1).Value = el        'jurisdiction
                        PutValues cOut.Offset(0, 2), arrG1  'group1
                        PutValues cOut.Offset(0, 27), arrG2 'group2
                        Set cOut = cOut.Offset(1) 'next output row
                    Next el
                
                End If
                Set rwData = rwData.Offset(1) 'next data row
            Loop
        End If      'tab name contains "exceptions"
    Next ws
End Sub

'If `arr` is not Empty, place it into a row starting at `c`
Sub PutValues(c As Range, arr)
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        c.Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
    End If
End Sub

'return an array of vbLf-separated non-blank values in a cell
Function CellValues(c As Range)
    Dim v As String, arr, col As New Collection, el
    v = Trim(c.Value)                      'remove any spaces
    If Len(v) > 0 Then                     'any content?
        arr = Split(v, vbLf)                       'split on vbLf
        For Each el In arr
            el = Trim(el)
            If Len(el) > 0 Then col.Add el 'non-blank?
        Next el
    End If
    CellValues = ColToArray(col)
End Function

'load a Collection to a 1D array
Function ColToArray(col As Collection)
    Dim i, arr
    If col.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arr(0 To col.Count - 1)
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            arr(i - 1) = col(i)
        Next i
        ColToArray = arr
    Else
        ColToArray = Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Added some code for your second use case....

Comment: Can't thank you enough Tim!! After initial glance this works great. I will dig in an review.      Happy Holidays!!

Comment: This works flawlessly. Thank you again so much for the additional effort!